# How to debug this Xcode stacktrace

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, healthkit

The crash happens with a Flutter app on <1% of devices (of all versions and models) when requesting the authorization for writing to Apple Health via a package (health_kit_reporter and HealthKitReporter).

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1add0d9d4 __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1c16beb54 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1adc1c4fc +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96 (NSException.m:146)
3   Foundation                      0x1aef14878 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 128 (NSException.m:231)
4   Flutter                         0x10585c82c -[FlutterStandardMethodCodec encodeErrorEnvelope:] + 196 (FlutterStandardCodec.mm:110)
5   Flutter                         0x1058597c8 __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 136 (FlutterChannels.mm:0)
6   health_kit_reporter             0x105152cbc thunk for @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned Swift.AnyObject?) -> () + 92 (<compiler-generated>:0)
7   health_kit_reporter             0x105161c2c closure #1 in SwiftHealthKitReporterPlugin.requestAuthorization(reporter:arguments:result:) + 320
8   health_kit_reporter             0x10516ca14 partial apply for closure #1 in SwiftHealthKitReporterPlugin.requestAuthorization(reporter:arguments:result:) + 72 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   HealthKitReporter               0x104dd875c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Bool, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 56 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  HealthKit                       0x1b7f9d21c __84-[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:shouldPrompt:completion:]_block_invoke + 368 (HKHealthStore.m:688)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad945298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1454)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad946280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:559)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad8eedcc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 612 (inline_internal.h:2548)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad8ef8d8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 472 (queue.c:3862)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad8f9338 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 712 (queue.c:6601)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1f43aa5a4 _pthread_wqthread + 272 (pthread.c:2206)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1f43ad874 start_wqthread + 8
```

[image]

Is there any information on why the crash happened?
Or is there a trick to reproduce errors during debugging with Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was fixed with the changes here:
https://github.com/VictorKachalov/health_kit_reporter/pull/25/files

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this error in my app. I have yet to verify this, but it looks like the issue is caused by [call in encodeErrorEnvelope](https://github.com/gaaclarke/engine/blob/237948d905603cdd05aa13f524dafaf9da0b2c93/shell/platform/darwin/common/framework/Source/FlutterStandardCodec.mm#L110) which tries to write error detail, and if such error detail is not encodable, it crashes the app.

Comment: My issue was probably fixed with this PR:
https://github.com/VictorKachalov/health_kit_reporter/pull/25